# android .so file's size on linux and windows

Tags: android

I have used bsdiff to implement my app updates.
As you knonw,I have to use ndk to compile a .so file and invoke the native method.
but I find that when I compile the same files, on ubuntu 12.04 the .so file's size is about 57KB,but  on windows xp,the .so file's size if about 156KB,how could this happend,and why these .so file's size not same

Comment: And both Ubuntu and Windows are running the exact same version of the NDK?

Comment: I opened RELEASE.TXT they are both r9

Comment: Compile settings are the same?

Comment: what does your mean about Compile setting?   one on windows xp, I used ndk r9 and another on ubuntu 12.04 I used ndk r9 too.